# Windows XP remote desktop connection to my system alters the files/ folder placement on my host desktop

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

Please let me know on how to stop my individual files/ folder placement on my desktop to disappear when someone connects to my system via remote desktop. All the icons/ files/folders cluster together at the top/left on the desktop after a remote desktop connection..

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: New to this forum.. I have the problem in XP and connection from another XP also does this. Please feel free to delete my post if you feel that this a duplicate. No resolution in the mentioned post as well :-(

Comment: welcome to super user,well the answer on that question might help you to solve your query

Comment: Adding a 3rd party software to achieve is good. However, my office IT guys wouldn't be too pleased about that :-). Should I conclude that there is no other way to achieve this through Windows OS settings?

Comment: You might try setting up separate user account(s) for the remote connections to use. That way they'll have their own desktops and icon positions what won't effect your own account's.